# A return statement with a return value cannot be used

Tags: sql, sql-server

I trying to determine if a reference number exists or not and when I run the query below I am getting an error

> Must declare the scalar variable @referencenumber.

Any idea why?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT ID, ReferenceNumber FROM tblData WHERE ReferenceNumber = @ReferenceNumber)  
THEN
   Return 1
ELSE
   Return 0
END IF
```

Comment: That error message pretty much says everything. How do you expect to get this running without declaring the variable?

Comment: How do I declare it? sorry new to this

Comment: The question is: how are you going to execute this?

Comment: In vb.net code: Try
                Dim Con As SqlConnection
                Dim cmd As SqlCommand
                Con = New SqlConnection
                Con.ConnectionString = ""
                Con.Open()

                cmd = New SqlCommand
                cmd.Connection = Con
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT

Comment: Post new code as an edit to your question, not as a comment.

Comment: `RETURN` only makes sense in a UDF or such - not in a general SQL query / DQL syntax. Please post the *complete* context and desired goal. Declaring a bound placeholder and declaring a UDF parameter are two different things.

Comment: Particularly: Are you calling a stored procedure, or is this inlined SQL commands?

Comment: Well because he hasn't tagged anything, I assumed he's using plain SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't tagged any programming language.
So on SQL-Server you can use `declare` and then set your specific value:

```
declare @ReferenceNumber int;
set @ReferenceNumber = 1000; --your reference number

IF EXISTS (SELECT ID, ReferenceNumber FROM tblData WHERE ReferenceNumber = @ReferenceNumber)  
THEN
   SELECT 1
ELSE
   SELECT 0
END IF
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure cmd.CommandType is set to Text

Also, you have to add your parameter to the Parameters collection...

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReferenceNumber", SqlDbType.Int); // Assuming Int, change to whatever you need
```

Then you have to set the value of your new parameter...

```
cmd.Parameters("@ReferenceNumber").Value = *The value*
```

Read more about using parameters [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)